# Thread 1: breakpoint 1.2; loading realm data into custom tableview using Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, realm

So I'm recently learning Realm database and loading the data into my custom tableview and I tried to use RLMResults as an array to get my data in the database and load the elements stored in my RLMResults to my tableview in the usual way. My ViewController.m is like this:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "customCell.h"
#import "Person.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property RLMRealm *realm;
@property RLMResults *person;
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize realm, person;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    Person *one = [[Person alloc] init];
    one.firstName = @"Allen";
    one.lastName = @"X";

    realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
    [realm beginWriteTransaction];
    [realm addObject:one];
    [realm commitWriteTransaction];

    self.person = [Person allObjects];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [person count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellIdentifier";
    customCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.firstName.text = [self.person[indexPath.row] firstName];
    cell.lastName.text = [self.person[indexPath.row] lastName];
    return cell;
}

@end
```

And once I compile and run this, Xcode would say things like this:
[Thread 1: breakpoint 1.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hgv3.png)

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

That would be due to the fact you you set a breakpoint (That blue arrow in the column next to your code), possibly by accident, at that portion of your code. ;)

If you click and drag the breakpoint into the column on the left, that'll delete it and your code should start running again on the next build. :)

(Additionally, here's [a page on Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/chapters/Creating,Disabling,andDeletingBreakpoints.html) that goes into more detail about what else you can do with breakpoints. Good luck! :) )

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm having PE class right now is and I'm gonna check it out right after my class is over.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Select **Exception** as **Objective-C**, it will work